# Iterate variable to next list item

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to increment a value (room) to the next item on a list (dungeon), so that I can create a random instance of rooms in a text adventure.

```
def dungeon_generator(): #used to generate random dungeon order
    dungeon = random.sample(range(2, 19), 8)
    dungeon.append(20) #used to add Boss
    dungeon[:0]=[1] #used to add Entrance
```

Pseudocode:

```
room = dungeon[0] #i.e. room == 1
while room != 0

    if room == 1:
        do things in room
        room finished
        room = NEXT number in dungeon list

    elif room == 2
        do things in room
        room finished
        room = NEXT number in dungeon list

etc

    elif room == 0
        game over
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to read the next item from the dungeon list? Because I've used `random.sample`, the list items will be unique if that helps.

Comment: You may want to consider having a set of Room classes with a method `do_things_in_room` (or a better name) instead of having to deal with numbers and long if/elif blocks.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

def dungeon_generator(): #used to generate random dungeon order
    dungeon = random.sample(range(2, 19), 8)
    dungeon.append(20) #used to add Boss    
    dungeon[:0]=[1] #used to add Entrance
    return dungeon


room = 0 #i.e. room == 1

dungeon = dungeon_generator();

while room < len(dungeon) and dungeon[room] != 0:
    if dungeon[room] == 1:        
        # do something
        print (dungeon[room])
    elif dungeon[room] == 2:
        # do something
        print (dungeon[room])
    room = room + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to access dungeon with.

```
roomNumber = 1
room = dungeon[roomNumber]

if room == 1:
    do things in room
    roomNumber += 1

etc...
```

This way, you don't need to manually keep track of indexes.

Comment: Wouldn't that just increment the room number sequentially though? Should it be roomNumber += 1 to increment the value it is reading from room? i.e. dungeon[0], dungeon[1], dungeon[2] etc. Apologies if I'm way off the mark, I've pretty new to Python.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Typo. Edited to reflect what I originally meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a for loop to iterate over the room numbers.

```
dungeon = [1, 3, 2, 20]

for room in dungeon:
    if room == 1:
        print('room 1')
    elif room == 2:
        print('room 2')
    elif room == 3:
        print('room 3')
    # etc.
```

---

If you want to try something fancier, you can define functions (or classes) for the different rooms and then add these functions to the `dungeon` list instead of numbers.

```
import random

def room1():
    print('In room1.')

def room2():
    print('In room2.')

def room3():
    print('In room3.')

def intro_room():
    print('Intro')

def boss_room():
    print('Boss')

def dungeon_generator():
    """Create a list of function objects (the rooms)."""
    dungeon = [intro_room]
    dungeon += random.sample((room1, room2, room3), 2)    
    dungeon.append(boss_room)
    return dungeon


dungeon = dungeon_generator()

for room in dungeon:  # Iterate over the room functions.
    room()  # Now call the current room function.
```